# How can I view the comments and answers to How do these 9 LePage Super Glues differ?

Tags: discussion

I bookmarked https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/222511/how-do-these-9-lepage-super-glues-differ. I wrote down that it got comments and answers. But why can't I see them anymore? Can anyone retrieve them please?

Comment: That question has been deleted, and from what I see it does not have any answers at all.

Comment: Also note, that this was one of several questions asked by a person who was requesting product comparisons/reviews. The StackExchange group of sites is _not_ in the business of doing product reviews/recommendations and that is why the question was closed, then deleted. There are many better places to get product reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no answers on that question, nor were there ever any answers on that question.

There are four comments, one linking to the first superglue question asked by that user, two noting that product reviews are off-topic, and one that doesn't address the question asked.

Comment: Thanks. Did that question get any comments?